# 'Untrusted domain' authentication error when using SQL authentication with SMO package

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I'm using the Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects NuGet package in a C# project to try and make a size-reduced copy of a database (by excluding certain large tables).

I'm using SQL authentication, but getting this error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
// Establish server connections:    
var sourceServerConn = new ServerConnection(sourceServerName, sourceUsername, sourcePassword);
var sourceServer = new Server(sourceServerConn);
var sourceDatabase = sourceServer.Databases[sourceDatabaseName];

var targetServerConn = new ServerConnection(targetServerName, targetUsername, targetPassword);
var targetServer = new Server(targetServerConn);
Database targetDatabase = null;

// Set server timeouts to unlimited:
sourceServer.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 0;
targetServer.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 0;

// Create db:
targetDatabase = new Database(targetServer, targetDatabaseName);
targetDatabase.Create();

// Create schema:
var transfer = new Transfer(sourceDatabase);
transfer.CopyAllObjects = true;
transfer.Options.WithDependencies = true;
transfer.DestinationDatabase = targetDatabase.Name;
transfer.DestinationServer = targetServer.Name;
transfer.DestinationLoginSecure = false;
transfer.DestinationLogin = targetUsername;
transfer.DestinationPassword = targetPassword;
transfer.CopySchema = true;
transfer.CopyData = false;
transfer.Options.ContinueScriptingOnError = true;

transferSchema.TransferData();
```

It seems that *somewhere* it's trying to use Windows authentication but my ServerConnection and Transfer objects are using sql authentication and I'm at a loss as to where this Windows authentication is arising?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/create-program/connecting-to-an-instance-of-sql-server about 2/3 of the way down the page there's an example that should help you. Try setting `server.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = False`

Comment: @JacobH Thanks for the answer, I don't think the issue is with the server connection though. 'new ServerConnection(sourceServerName, sourceUsername, sourcePassword)' implicitly sets the authentication as sql and the username and password. The error I get is unchanged by adapting my code to the format used in the example you linked.